# How to use CRT batch technique in Microsoft SEAL 3.1?

Tags: c++, encryption, seal, post-quantum-cryptography

Can you please tell me whether SEAL 3.1 supports PolyCRTBuilder class? I am trying to run the following program but failed because the class is not declared in this scope.

/**
Suppose I have two arrays `x = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `xMean = [3,3,3,3,3]`. I composed and encrypted the two array using PolyCRTBuilder ( xCiphertext and xMeanCiphertext ) . If I subtract the two ciphertexts ( xCiphertext MINUS xMeanCiphertext ), I should get `xResult = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]` but after the homomorphic subtraction I am getting `xResultDecrypted = [40959, 40960, 0 ,1, 2]` . I can relate the overflow result to the plain modulus set but is there a work around for this problem. Here is the code:
*/

```
#include <iostream>
#include "seal/seal.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace seal;

/*
Helper function: Prints the parameters in a SEALContext.
*/
void print_parameters(shared_ptr<SEALContext> context)
{
    // Verify parameters

    if (!context)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("context is not set");
    }
    auto &context_data = *context->context_data();

    /*
    Which scheme are we using?
    */
    string scheme_name;
    switch (context_data.parms().scheme())
    {
    case scheme_type::BFV:scheme_name = "BFV";
        break;
    case scheme_type::CKKS:scheme_name = "CKKS";
        break;
    default:
        throw invalid_argument("unsupported scheme");
    }

    cout << "/ Encryption parameters:" << endl;
    cout << "| scheme: " << scheme_name << endl;
    cout << "| poly_modulus_degree: " << context_data.parms().poly_modulus_degree() << endl;

    /*
    Print the size of the true (product) coefficient modulus.
    */
    cout << "| coeff_modulus size: " << context_data.
        total_coeff_modulus_bit_count() << " bits" << endl;

    /*
    For the BFV scheme print the plain_modulus parameter.
    */
    if (context_data.parms().scheme() == scheme_type::BFV)
    {
        cout << "| plain_modulus: " << context_data.
            parms().plain_modulus().value() << endl;
    }

    cout << "\\ noise_standard_deviation: " << context_data.
        parms().noise_standard_deviation() << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    cout << "\nTotal memory allocated from the current memory pool: "<< (MemoryManager::GetPool().alloc_byte_count() >> 20) << " MB" << endl;
    EncryptionParameters parms(scheme_type::BFV);
    //EncryptionParameters parms;
    parms.set_poly_modulus_degree(4096);
    parms.set_coeff_modulus(coeff_modulus_128(4096));
    parms.set_plain_modulus(40961); ////Make the coefficient modulus prime>2n to enable CRT batching

    auto context = SEALContext::Create(parms);
    print_parameters(context);
    IntegerEncoder encoder(parms.plain_modulus());

    KeyGenerator keygen(context);
    PublicKey public_key = keygen.public_key();
    SecretKey secret_key = keygen.secret_key();
    // SEALContext context(parms);

    // KeyGenerator keygen(context);
    // auto public_key = keygen.public_key();
    // auto secret_key = keygen.secret_key();

    Encryptor encryptor(context, public_key);
    Evaluator evaluator(context);
    Decryptor decryptor(context, secret_key);

    PolyCRTBuilder crtbuilder(context);

    int slot_count = crtbuilder.slot_count();
    int row_size = slot_count / 2;

    vector<uint64_t> x_pod_matrix(slot_count, 0);
    x_pod_matrix[0] = 1;
    x_pod_matrix[1] = 2;
    x_pod_matrix[2] = 3;
    x_pod_matrix[3] = 4;
    x_pod_matrix[4] = 5;

    Plaintext x_plain_matrix;
    crtbuilder.compose(x_pod_matrix, x_plain_matrix);

    Ciphertext x_encrypted_matrix;

    encryptor.encrypt(x_plain_matrix, x_encrypted_matrix);

    vector<uint64_t> x_mean_pod_matrix(slot_count, 0);
    x_mean_pod_matrix[0] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[1] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[2] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[3] = 3;
    x_mean_pod_matrix[4] = 3;

    Plaintext x_mean_plain_matrix;
    crtbuilder.compose(x_mean_pod_matrix, x_mean_plain_matrix);

    Ciphertext x_mean_encrypted_matrix;

    encryptor.encrypt(x_mean_plain_matrix, x_mean_encrypted_matrix);

    evaluator.sub_plain(x_encrypted_matrix, x_mean_encrypted_matrix);

    // Decrypt x_encrypted_matrix
    Plaintext x_plain_result;

    decryptor.decrypt(x_encrypted_matrix, x_plain_result);

    vector<uint64_t> pod_result;

    crtbuilder.decompose(x_plain_result, pod_result);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {

        std::cout << pod_result[i] << '\n';

    }

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

`PolyCRTBuilder` has been renamed to `BatchEncoder`. Take a look at the `src/examples` directory in SEAL v3.1 (or `native/examples` in a newer version) and you'll see plenty of examples.

Kind of related to your question: the `coeff_modulus_128` function hasn't existed in SEAL for quite a while; the same functionality is provided by the `CoeffModulus::BFVDefault` function. With these changes your code might work in SEAL 3.5 even.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It works fine. By the way, how can we print the encrypted ciphertext to check its nature of the polynomial form? I have tried x_encrypted_matrix.to_string() for the above code but it shows error. Moreover, Can we use add_many function after multiplying two vectors to get the inner product of two vectors using CRT packing?

Comment: There is no reasonable way to print a ciphertext polynomial. They are stored in an RNS representation (modulo each of the `coeff_modulus` primes), and may be in an NTT transformed form as well (default for CKKS). Also, they are huge in size, so I'm not sure what you would learn from inspecting it.

For your other question about slot summation, I would recommend creating a separate SO question entirely. This must be done using repeated (logarithmically many) rotations and additions; to be clear, `add_many` is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. It makes sense to me. I will make a new SO question.